# Count items in array with Liquid

Tags: ruby, liquid

I have a json object like the following:

```rb
    "results"=>{
        "data"=>[
            {
                "id"=>"letters",
                "values"=>["A", "B", "B", "X"]
            },
        ]
    }
```

I am trying to count how many `A`'s and how many `B`'s and then add them.

This is my code so far:

```rb
require 'liquid'
Liquid::Template.error_mode = :strict
@template = Liquid::Template.parse('
    {% assign letters = results.data | where: "id", "letters" %}
    {{ letters }}
    {% increment a_count %}
    {% increment b_count %}
    {% for letter in letters.values %}
        {% if letter contains "A" %}
            {% increment a_count %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if letter contains "B" %}
            {% increment b_count %}
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        The collection is empty.
    {% endfor %}
    {% assign count = a_count | plus: b_count %}
    {{ a_count}} + {{ b_count }} = {{ count }}
')
print(@template.render(
    "results"=> {
        "data"=> [
            {
                "id"=> "letters",
                "values"=> ["A", "B", "B", "X"]
            },
        ]
    }
), { strict_variables: true })
print(@template.errors)
```

But this doesn't work and I get this output:

```
    {"id"=>"letters", "values"=>["A", "B", "B", "X"]}
    0
    0

        The collection is empty.


    1 + 1 = 2
```

Which is confusing because `results.values` is not empty and I only call `increment` once for each `a_count` and `b_count` which should set the initial value to `0`.

The output of `print(@template.errors)` is only:

```
{:strict_variables=>true}[]
```

How do I count how many `A`'s and how many `B`'s are in the `letters.values` array?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to combine it with JS?
You can pass the array to a JS function and do there ther rest.